# How to fix: AttributeError: module 'twint' has no attribute 'config'

Tags: python-3.x, config, python-module, attributeerror

I have installed twint with:

```
pip3 install twint
```

which resulted in a successful installation:

```
Successfully installed twint-2.1.8
```

It works to get tweets from `twitter` using Command Prompt(CLI) commands but when I try to run the example in `Spyder` IDE it gives me the error:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<ipython-input-13-7b77905cef0c>", line 1, in <module>
        runfile('C:/Users/myname/twint.py', wdir='C:/Users/myname')
      File "C:\Users\myname\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
       execfile(filename, namespace)
      File "C:\Users\myname\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
        exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
      File "C:/Users/myname/twint.py", line 8, in <module>
        import twint
      File "C:\Users\myname\twint.py", line 9, in <module>
        c = twint.Config()
    AttributeError: module 'twint' has no attribute 'Config'
```

Here is my code:

```
import twint
c = twint.Config()
c.Username = "twitterAccountName"
twint.run.Search(c)
```

However, I looked twint related issues on GitHub found [here](https://github.com/twintproject/twint/issues/92) but the solution provided here not worked for me. Does anyone know where the error coming from? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The issue you linked to is the exact same problem you have. You need to rename your file to not be twint.py

Rename this file `runfile('C:/Users/myname/twint.py`

If you get other errors, then that's a separate issue

Comment: `@cricket_007` I changed the file name as `scrape.py` but not solved. It gives me the same `AttributeError`

Comment: @OneCricketeer this fixed my issue thanks!